# About MongoDb sharding

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I’m facing a deployment issue for my product. I have to deploy it on a couple of servers which are located on different countries. My product has 3 main components:

- Application server: server and database (I'm using MongoDb)
- User app: communicates with application server
- Web server
  [image]

Every application server can working independently. The requirements are:

- The web server can access to all Databases and treat them as 1 single database.
- The data of Application server 1 must be stored on its own database (not on Application server 2, or 3, or so on).

After googling around, 1 solution is **deploying sharded clusters**. Because I’ve never done this before, so is it a good idea? Will it meet the requirements? What points that I have to pay attention to when doing this? If it is not a good idea, please show me a good way to solve the problem.

Thank you very much.

Comment: do these 3 app servers run different applications? Or same code but different data?

Comment: They are running the same code with a some different configuration. The databases have the same models.

Comment: Hi @SergioTulentsev, are you still there?

Comment: Yep, I'm always here :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, could you please give me some advice. Thank you :)

Comment: Your requirements are mutually exclusive. Either you view it as a single database, or independent ones. Sharding won't help here.